# Contains of textbox to array - C#

Tags: c#, textbox, boolean

I have a textbox filled with boolean. How do I put the contents into an array?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question: a textbox holds a single value, whereas an array holds many values.

Comment: Suppose, checkbox would be a better choice for a boolean value.

Comment: You just blew my mind...

Comment: @ShellShock:  TextBox can also hold multiline (TextBox.Multiline=true).  In that case you can use the TextBox.Lines property to read the text as string[].

Answer (score 4):

Is it a string like this?

```
True False True True False False True
```

If so, try this:

```
bool[] contents = myTextBox.Text.Split(' ') // or whatever your split char is
    .Select(s => bool.Parse(s))
    .ToArray();
```

A more robust approach would be to ignore invalid values by using `bool.TryParse`:

```
bool[] contents = myTextBox.Text.Split(' ') // or whatever
    .Where(s => { bool discard; return bool.TryParse(s, out discard); })
    .Select(s => bool.Parse(s)) // a little redundant, but clean
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The textbox has a string representation of a Boolean; you need to cast it:

bool myBool = bool.Parse(myTbox.Text);

And then put it in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is

```
 bool myBool;
 if (!bool.TryParse(myTbox.Text, out myBool))
  MessageBox.Show("Cannot convert text to bool.");
```